# irssi: how to hide names when joining channel?

Tags: irssi

In irssi, every time I join a channel, a full listing of names is displayed. This is particularly annoying when channels are re-joined due to connection issues (slack irc gateways are particularly problematic for this).

Is there any way to hide, suppress or redirect this name output to a different window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't currently have `irssi` installed, but the `show_names_on_join` option seems to control the behavior you are talking about.

https://irssi.org/documentation/settings/#show_names_on_join

Comment: Thanks! This can be set by the command __/set show_names_on_join OFF__, or adding __show_names_on_join = "no";__ to the __settings / fe-common/core__ section of .irssi/config